# Grey-out a tab/menu item if bean has 'false' boolean value

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a home page with numerous menu/tab items that simply redirects the user when clicked BUT they must have access to the menu item they're clicking. If they don't, it is simply unclickable. This functionality works but I would like to grey-out the menu item if the user does not have access. Please see example:

```
<div class="sidenav"> 
   <a 
     [ngClass]="{'menuitem': true,'activemenu':currentPage=='reporting' }" 
     [class.disabled]="!home.reportAccess" 
     (click)="navigateToPage('reporting',home.reportAccess)"  
     role="text">
       <img src=".\assets\images\monotone_arrow_play_right_next1.png">Reporting
   </a>
</div>
```

This simply checks the reportAccess bean and if false, do not allow the user to click/redirect to this page. I would love to create a grey ascent to this tab so the user knows, visually, they're unable to access this page. I would like to add this, in addition to the implementation already present. Anyone have any suggestions? I am new to front-end web development by the way. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you disabled the link using `!home.reportAccess` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Sanira's answer, this is what I came up with:

```
<div class="sidenav"> 
   <a 
     [ngClass]="{'menuitem': true,'activemenu':currentPage=='reporting','gray-nav': home.reportAccess==false }" 
     [class.disabled]="!home.reportAccess" 
     (click)="navigateToPage('reporting',home.reportAccess)" role="text">
     <img src=".\assets\images\monotone_arrow_play_right_next1.png">Reporting
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gray-nav {
      background-color: gray;
      pointer-events:none;
}
```

This works as intended. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same boolean to add a CSS class to change the color.

```
<div class="sidenav"> 
   <a 
     [ngClass]="{'menuitem': true,'activemenu':currentPage=='reporting', !home.reportAccess ? 'disabled-style' : '' }" 
     [class.disabled]="!home.reportAccess" 
     (click)="navigateToPage('reporting',home.reportAccess)"  
     role="text">
       <img src=".\assets\images\monotone_arrow_play_right_next1.png">Reporting
   </a>
</div>
```